# JS Percentage Calculation in a single line?

Tags: javascript

I am calculating the percentage increase between two numbers , based on the formula

```
newnumber - oldnumber 
----------------------- * 100
  oldnumber 




var oldNumber = 33, newNumber = 40;

var percent = newNumber - oldNumber;

var percent2 = percent/oldNumber;

var PercenIncr = Math.ceil(percent2*100).toFixed(2);

alert(PercenIncr)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/416jkaz7/2/

Can i do all this in a single line ?

Comment: How about this one var PercenIncr = Math.ceil(((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2); ?

Comment: If you just replace the variables, you have it: `Math.ceil(((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2);`. Have in mind that you can simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
var oldNumber = 33, newNumber = 40;
var PercenIncr = Math.ceil(((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2);
alert(PercenIncr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the (perfectly correct) answer from @ellipsis, you could also create a function to do this even more succinctly.

```js
const percentIncrease = (oldNumber, newNumber) => Math.ceil(((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2);

alert(percentIncrease(33,40)); // => 22.00
alert(percentIncrease(55,72)); // => 31.00
```

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by the comment @svenQ, arrow functions (`=>`) are not supported in IE11 or below. You would therefore need to do something like this for older browsers:

```
var percentIncrease = function(oldNumber, newNumber) {
    return Math.ceil(((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2)
}
```

You can also use polyfills or services like Babel compile your JavaScript for older browsers

Comment: But know that you can need to make sure to use a polyfill then, since arrow functions are not supported in IE11

Comment: Code will be even more attractive when using `oldNumber` and `newNumber`  (As mentioned in the question) instead of `a` and `b` respectively.

Comment: Updated as per your recommendation, @Praveen

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,
this code will get you two decimal positions also.

```
var oldNumber = 33, newNumber = 40;
var incr = (((newNumber - oldNumber)/oldNumber)*100).toFixed(2);
alert(incr);
```